# Flutter shared prefs vs. native shared prefs

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, sharedpreferences

Flutter's shared preferences library has a setStringList function, but no setStringSet function. However, in the Kotlin API, there's only a getStringSet function and no list counterpart.

I need to read the list of sharedprefs saved for a key from Kotlin, but they were saved using Flutter using setStringList. Very unclear how to do this (and I'm guessing it must be possible) from the API documentation.

Any advice?

Update: The key used to setStringList from flutter works with getString from Kotlin, so I guess the set is saved as a string. But the string value seems to be an encoded version of the set. To be precised:

Flutter:
`List<String> values = [...];
 prefs.setStringList('key', values);`

Kotlin:
`var values = prefs.getString("key")`

returns non-null values, however it's not a readable string, but some sort of encoding?